# Subtour Elimination in Travelling Salesman Problem using MTZ

Tags: integer-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to formulation a problem similar to a Traveling Salesman with Time Window constraints.

To eliminate subtours, I need to use some constraint similar to a generalization of MTZ constraints like the following:

> r_i + t_ij - M*(1-x_ij) <= r_j

where "r_i" is the arrival time at node i, "x_ij" is the binary variable showing inclusion of arc i --> j (similar to general TSP formulations), "t_ij" is travel time from i to j and "M" is a big number.

The problem is that in the specific setup of my problem, I have pairs of nodes with t_ij = 0, i.e. there are at least two nodes i and j such that t_ij = t_ji = 0.

Now apparently this specific setup of distances ends up in creation of subtour in my solution, even with the above MTZ-like constraints.

Has anybody had a similar experience? Is there a  way to perturb the above constraint to prevent any possible subtours?